# how to find a character and read what's before it

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    string getEmail;
    
    string email, firstName, lastName;
    char dot = '.';
    cout << "What is your email?" << endl;
    getline(cin, email);
    
    double pos = email.find(dot);
    firstName = //store every letter before the dot;
    cout << firstName << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I read the email, let's say I encounter `'.'`, I want to read the word before it. For example: `Yes.no`. I find `'.'` and read `Yes` and store it in a variable.

Comment: You have it all in the string `email`. You can extract the [*sub-string*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: Also note that string positions can't be floating-point values. You can get a position 2.5 characters into a string, what would that even mean? All string positions are equivalent to the index, so `0` is the first character in the string, `1` is the second, etc. And all those numbers are integers.

Comment: Can you please explain how to extract it

Comment: Please follow the link to the `substr` reference. Read about the function. Read about its arguments. ***Experiment!***

Answer (score 2):

Why is `pos` a `double`? Positions are **integers**. For positions in strings there is a special integer type called `size_t`, so your code should be

```
size_t pos = email.find(dot);
```

To get the first part of the email address you can use the `substr` method. It has two parameters, a position (where the substring starts) and a count (how many characters in the substring). So to get the first part of the string you say

```
firstName = email.substr(0, pos);
```

Note that if `email` does not contain a dot then this code will put the whole string into `firstName`. If you want to test for that then you do it like this

```
size_t pos = email.find(dot);
if (pos == string::npos)               // if no dot
    cout << "no dot in email address";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `substr()` should be the solution to this, but seems like the datatype of `pos` is not necessary to be a `double`, should be an integer.

```
int main()
{
    string getEmail;
    
    string email, firstName, lastName;
    char dot = '.';
    cout << "What is your email?" << endl;
    getline(cin, email);
    
    size_t pos = email.find(dot);
    firstName = email.substr(0, pos);
    cout << firstName << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find regular expressions useful for parsing strings.

They let you:

- match an input string against a pattern, and
- grab different parts of the matched string at once (e.g. full email, first name, second name, domain...).

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/85jWj1z34)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::regex pattern{ R"((\w+)\.(\w+)@.+)" };
    for (std::string email : { "john.doe@xyz.com", "anne.doe@abc.org", "foo@so.com" }) {
        std::smatch matches{};
        if (std::regex_match(email, matches, pattern)) {
            fmt::print("email: '{}', first name: '{}', second name: '{}'\n",
                matches[0].str(), matches[1].str(), matches[2].str());
        } else {
            fmt::print("Warning: username does not contain a dot: '{}'.\n", email);
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   email: 'john.doe@xyz.com', first name: 'john', second name: 'doe'
//   email: 'anne.doe@abc.org', first name: 'anne', second name: 'doe'
//   Warning: username does not contain a dot: 'foo@so.com'.
```